# Use Queries to Count the Number of Data Between Several Values

Tags: sql, ms-access, bar-chart

I am trying to output a Package Size graph. This is a graph that tells you how many projects you have which are spending between 2 amounts.

For example:

```
Project Spend
1000
1500
35000
36500
40000
55000
89000
105000
110000
140000
```

A package size chart produces a bar chart. In this case the data would be.

```
Between                      £0-£50000   £50000-£100000   £100000+
Number of Projects in Band       5             2             3
```

How can I get MS Access 2007 to produce the desired bar chart using queries?

Comment: Take a look at the pivot function http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use conditional aggregation, where you use `iif()` with `sum()`:

```
select "Number of Projects in band" as which,
       sum(iif(ProjectSpend between 0 and 49999, 1, 0)) as band1,
       sum(iif(ProjectSpend between 50000 and 99999, 1, 0)) as band2,
       sum(iif(ProjectSpend >= 100000, 1, 0)) as band3
from yourtable as t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'Number of Projects in Band' AS [Between]
(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE [Project Spend] BETWEEN 0 AND 50000
)AS [£0-£50000],
(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE [Project Spend] BETWEEN 50000 AND 100000
)AS [£50000-£100000],
(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE [Project Spend] > 100000
)AS [£100000+]
```